# Can the words "With Less" mean "with less money" without adding the word "money"

Tags: meaning, speech

I am trying to write an ebook about the things you can make yourself with less resources and money. The title with be something like "Build it yourself with less".

My question is: Do I have to add the word "money" at the end of the title to let people know that I mean "with less money". The reason I am asking this is that I don't like having the word "money" on my title.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Does "Make it yourself for little" give better meaning than "Make it yourself with less" that I mean money?

Comment: How about "Build it yourself cheaper"?  I know that cheaper is sometimes interpreted as "lesser quality", but I thought you might like it anyway.

Comment: @James I'd want 'Build it cheaper yourself' or 'Build it yourself – cheaper!'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  For some reason that reminds me of my favorite book title, "Eat Yourself Super". http://www.amazon.com/Eat-Yourself-Super-Bite-Time/dp/1614481679

Comment: "Build it yourself *for* less" would be idiomatic.  "For less" (somehow) implies money, while "with less" leaves one wondering "less what?"

Comment: ("Make it yourself for little" really sucks.)

Answer (score 5):

Everyone will have differing opinions on this, however I think the title would be better if you changed it to "Build it for Less."  This has the money feel to it without the word "money" in the title.

Again, just my opinion, but I'm not quite comfortable with the "with less."  It doesn't match "resources" which in my opinion should take fewer, and how can you build something with money, or for that matter use money to build something?  You pay "for" the resources with money.

Comment: @JackHill it wouldn't confuse people...two people here already think it's ok.  What about "Builditforless.com" You could say "Build it yourself for less."  Yourself has a nice self-reliance feel to it, and people who are self reliant like to save money.

Comment: Make it for little doesn't mean much and in any case, I'm not sure a word like "little" can follow "for."  I'm pretty sure it can't.

Comment: Thanks for reply, just one question. If "for" was not available what would you use with "Build it yourself ....". Thanks.

Comment: @JackHill I'd have to think for a bit.  I would probably change the title...maybe "Building it yourself for less."  Or something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use 'for' *(Make it yourself for less)* (a title already taken?).  How about ***Build it yourself and save!***

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I would say this was fine.  **With less** implies less money and resources on its own, and it's not a very rare thing to do.

(If you google "with less" for example, you'll probably find a few organizations that have those words in their title, and they focus on doing whatever it is with less money/resources)

Comment: Without additional context, I'd not assume that money rather than materials was necessarily implied.

Comment: That's right, but you don't generally see the words "with less" standing alone.

Comment: They don't stand alone in OP's 'Build it yourself with less.' I'd say that materials / tools etc is a fair guess here.

Comment: *Make it yourself with less* also hints/suggests (wrongly, I realise, but the association cannot be unmade in my mind)  that I will be making something that is less good.  Not a good marketing message.  I suppose I want to spend less but believe that my materials are as good as 'full price' materials (i.e. my savings are due to my doing it myself and not to my using cheap, second-rate materials).

Answer (score 0):

> ### ~~Building~~
>
> **-for those with less-**

The commonly understood idiom is *"those with less"* (with 45 million Google hits), otherwise yes, you have to mention money. Also, consider using the word *homemaking* instead of *building*.